# Need a method called after on touch has completed

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener, ontouch

In our android program we are having trouble getting a method to call at the right time. We have an ontouchlistener and we tried to have it called on release, meaning the other functions would proceed it. However, it appears everything in "ontouch" happens at the same time. How do we get this other method to be called after the others have completed?

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    Tile touchedTile = (Tile) v;
    if (touchedTile.isEmpty() || !touchedTile.isInRowOrColumnOf(emptyTile)) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        mediaPlayer.start();
        if (event.getActionMasked() ==  MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            movedTile = touchedTile;
            currentMovement = getTilesBetweenEmptyTileAndTile(movedTile);
            //movedTile.numberOfMoves = 0;
        }
        else if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            if (lastDragPoint != null) {
                followFinger(event);
            }
            lastDragPoint = new PointF(event.getRawX(), event.getRawY());
        }
        else if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            currentMovement = getTilesBetweenEmptyTileAndTile(movedTile);

            if (lastDragMovedAtLeastHalfway() || isClicked()) {
                animateTilesToEmptySpace();
                checkMatch();
            }
            else {
                animateTilesBackToOrigin();
            }

            currentMovement = null;
            lastDragPoint = null;
            movedTile = null;

        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `onTouch` is called multiple times; there are down, move and up events, among others.  Why do you say they all happen at the same time?

Comment: @pathfinderelite This is how it seems to be happening. We have the methods we want called inside onTouch, but one is dependent on another happening before it. However it fails the check until after the next touch event occurs, because it seems to account for before the other methods happen.

Comment: Can you post your `onTouch` code?

Comment: @pathfinderelite I added it. checkMatch needs to occur after animateTilesToEmptySpace

Comment: So you want `checkMatch` to execute after the animation has completed?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to extend the view where you're setting the `OnTouchListener` and override the method `onTouchEvent` from that view. Call the super, after invoke your own methods, that way you ensure that they will be triggered before the `onTouchLister`. Let me know if that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a complex listener, you should look at [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html), So for `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` the doc says:

> ... A pressed gesture has finished, the motion contains the final release location as well as any intermediate points since the last down or move event....

There is a lot of info about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // I just put my finger on the view
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // I am moving my finger over the screen
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // I have just released my finger from the screen
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** looks like you're trying to make a jigsaw puzzle app with one empty cell.
Considering you must be using an animator object, u also must have registered an on animate update listener. Shouldn't you put the checkMatch() method inside it so that it gets called whenever the animation ends, since a match will occur only after the user moves tiles?